# using the sort() method on a vector of pointers to an abstract class

Tags: c++

Good morning!
I used the sort method of  to sort a vector. However, I get an error saying "`error: must use '.*' or '->*'`".
I spent a lot of time on google last night, but didn't manage to figure out how to solve this issue.

This is my code:

```
 bool Directory::pointerStringSort(BaseFile *file1, BaseFile *file2) {
    return file1->getName() < file2->getName();

void Directory::sortByName() {
    if (children.empty()) return;
    sort(children.begin(), children.end(), pointerStringSort);
```

full error:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Directory::*)(BaseFile*, BaseFile*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Directory::*)(BaseFile*, BaseFile*)>::_M_comp (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Directory::*)(BaseFile*, BaseFile*)>*)this)->__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_comp_iter<bool (Directory::*)(BaseFile*, BaseFile*)>::_M_comp) (...)'
{ return bool(_M_comp(__val, *__it)); }
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Make `pointerStringSort` a static member function

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The code you provided is not complete enough to produce the listed error message. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`_M_comp()` has to be either a functional object without context, i.e. no 'this' required, or an object with overloaded `operator()`. In the case of latter, you would have to provide an actual instance. The options are:

1. provide a free function;
2. provide a static function in a class;
3. provide a lambda;
4. provide an instance of an object with overloaded `operator()`

Learn more: [Compare concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare).

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

As StoryTeller notes, you'll want to declare `Directory::pointerStringSort` as a `static` method of `Directory`.

Furthermore, you want to pass `&Directory::pointerStringSort` to `std::sort`. For backward compatibility with C, ordinary functions don't require an ampersand to take their address (implicit conversion). This applies only to functions, not objects, and in C++ this exception doesn't apply to member functions either (C didn't have them)

Comment: Hang on. Can you quote the standard on the last paragraph? Static member functions are in many regards "regular functions". IIRC they *will* decay.

Comment: @StoryTeller They will. Unless compilers have been broken for years.

Comment: @StoryTeller: It's one of those things where I'm not wasting grey matter. I know MSVC is being far too lenient in this area, and by using `&ClassName::` consistently I avoid portability issues. It's never wrong, and IMO better style. But the Standard doesn't cover style, no.

Comment: @MSalters - Normally I'd agree with you. But when Clang and GCC are both on the same page as MSVC, I fear you may be imparting the wrong impression on to the OP.

Comment: _A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses. [...] Neither does qualified-id, because there is no implicit conversion from a qualified-id for a non-static member function to the type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of function type to the type “pointer to function”_

Comment: So apparently, pointer to member function is the exception, instead of static member function. Unless explicitly said, function to pointer conversion is always implicit

Comment: Yeah, that's one of those things. A pointer to a static member function is not a "pointer-to-member", despite static member functions being proper members in other cases such as access control.